# Does the metric "total_interactions" from "IG User / Insights API" show only organic number?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Could you please tell me what interactions I get when I want 'total_interactions' metric (from Instagram Graph API / IG User / Insights)?

The value of the metric "total_interactions" from IG User / Insights is less than the value of Instagram paid post engagements

In the API [limitations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights/#:%7E:text=The%20API%20only%20reports%20organic%20interaction%20metrics%3B%20interactions%20on%20ads%20containing%20a%20media%20object%20are%20not%20counted) it says "The API only reports organic interaction metrics", but how come it is called "total_interactions" if it is supposed to show a total number.